# Ошибка ValueError: Can only create a chararray from string data в numpy.vectorize

Tags: python, numpy

```py
img_HSV = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_HSV, (3,3),0)
img_HSV[:, :, 0] = np.floor(img_HSV[:, :, 0] / 22.5).astype(np.uint8)
img_HSV[:, :, 1:] = np.floor(img_HSV[:, :, 1:] / 32).astype(np.uint8)
binarize = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.binary_repr(x, width=3))
img_HSV = binarize(img_HSV)
img_HSV = np.char.array(img_HSV[:, :, 0]) + np.char.array(img_HSV[:, :, 1]) + np.char.array(img_HSV[:, :, 2])
intarize = np.vectorize(lambda x: int(x, 2)) # в int
img_HSV = intarize(img_HSV)
```

Пытаюсь перевести HSV изображение в 512 цветов, но получаю ошибку

`ValueError: Can only create a chararray from string data.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это решило проблему

`img_HSV = np.core.defchararray.add(np.core.defchararray.add((img_HSV[:, :, 0]), img_HSV[:, :, 1]), img_HSV[:, :, 2])`